# What does green folder icon in github web interface mean?

Tags: git, github

I wanted to add some folder in my current git repo.

but i have received such green folder in the github the following image . How to add this folder into this project.[image: Green folder git]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the green folders represent submodules on github. A submodule is essentially a link to a version of another repo.

To get the submodules locally run:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

You can read more about submodules here:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: how to add this submodule as regular folder to my project.

Comment: Once you have the submodule sources locally you can remove the submodule from the repo and then just add the sources normally. But it's a little tricky to remove a submodule. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule

Answer (score 2):

That folder icon is how Github shows [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

A submodule is essentially a reference to another repository (specifically, a specific commit in another repository)

There should be a `.gitmodules` file at the root of the repository, containing something like this:

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "ca_log_analysis"]
      path = ca_log_analysis
      url = git://github.com/example/ca_log_analysis_repo.git
```

You could commit your changes to *that* linked repository, then update the master project to look at the new commit. The [Git book chapter on submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) should explain things

Answer (score 0):

From memory, Git doesn't recognise empty folders. Do you have anything in it? If not, add a README or something too.