# Git submodules in .gitmodules not initialized

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

https://github.com/Uni-/shBrushesCollection

I created a GitHub repository and made a .gitmodules file directly from GitHub's web source editor. When I then cloned the repo, I noticed the submodules in .gitmodules were not being initialized.

I think I tried almost all commands possible, including update, init, update --init and so on. Is there a way to use current .gitmodules file, not submodules add?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing a submodule isn't enough.

You should rather use [`git submodule add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule): that will update your `.gitmodules` file *and* create a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) (where you want that submodule to be loaded).

Then, when you push that to your upstream repo on GitHub, the project page will display those special entries as a [green folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16301338/6309).

[image: green folder]

Comment: Thanks. So it's because there is no `gitlink` object... Then **why** does `.gitmodules` exist, while `.git/config` is what really works?

Comment: @Uni- because `.git/config` is purely a *local* configuration which isn't pushed/pulled. `.gitmodules` is a file which *declares* those submodules, part of the repo, pushed to other repos, and allowing any local repo cloning that file to build back its local `.git/config` with said submodules.

Answer (score 0):

✓ `.gitmodules` exists,
✓ submodule directory exists,
✗ but no files or sub-directories are in the submodule directory, ...

`git submodule update --init` is required, once, for this remote clone.