# GitHub include from another repository

Tags: git, github

I'm new to github.

I have a github repo on my machine. I want to include another repo (as a third party) into my repo. I believe I should make a fork first. But how do I include it on my local repo?

I've tried submodules but with no success...

Thanks.

Comment: You do not need a submodule unless you want to make it easier to automatically include another git repository. It is the recommended way though. If you want a quick test then just clone the repository into yours and work away. You will not go to far wrong. The root of each git repo will have a `.git` for that repo, using submodules will allow your repo to know about the other one, otherwise you are hiding it from yours.

Comment: In what way did using submodules result in 'no success'?

Answer (score 34):

[git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) remains the recommended way: you can declare ([`git submodule add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)) a repo which doesn't belong to you, or a fork (which, [by definition, belongs to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286571/git-fork-is-git-clone/6286877#6286877)).

Don't forget though, that:

- you still need to `git submodule update --init` in order to see that submodule repo being displayed with its full content in your repo
- add and commit the [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992018/git-submodule-update-needed-only-initially/2227598#2227598) representing the root directory of that submodule in your main (parent) repo, and [push that commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309), in order to validate that declaration.

Comment: This answer is generalized for Git.  The OP asked about GitHub, which presumably uses its own client.