# Git Submodules new Branch on parent dir

Tags: git, git-submodules

If I have a project that contains a number of submodules, and I switch to a new branch, from the parent directory, will it include those submodules in my new branch? How will they be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submodule is a SHA1 entry recorded [in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309) as a **[special entry 160000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309)**.

When you change branches, your index will reflect the SHA1 of those same submodules are recorded in that new branch.
A `git submodule update --init --recursive` will update said submodules.

That means you can have different version of the same submodule, as referenced by different branches.

Remmeber:

- Whatever branch you chose in the *parent* repo, the submodules are always in a detached HEAD mode (unless you go in a submodule, and checkout a branch there)
- You need to configure a submodule a certain way (see "[`git submodule` tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)") in order for it to follow its own upstream branch (you can [convert an existing submodule to that mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)).
  And you would need to make a `submodule update --remote` from the parent repo in order to trigger a fetch from the submodule configured to follow a branch.