# Cannot commit the line `Subproject commit`

Tags: macos, git, github

In one of my projects monitored by git, I git cloned another repo from Github. Now I noticed that in the software `Github for Mac`, there are changes about `Subproject commit`. Somehow git is referring to the cloned directory as a file with 2 lines?

[image]

Trying to commit the changes will throw me the error

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   packages/meteor-meteor (untracked content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
 (1)
```

Doing `git add .` still gives me the same error when doing a commit. What is happening here? I do not need to track/commit/push any changes on the cloned repo, just need to pull new updates when available.

Comment: you can remove .git in subproject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Somehow git is referring to the cloned directory as a file with 2 lines?

It is called a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.
you can see it declare in your `.gitmodules` file.

If you change anything within `packages/meteor-meteor`, the status of the parent repo (which contain that submodule) will reflect the "dirty" (modified) state of that submodule.

What you see is the SHA1 registered as a **[special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309)** in [the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309) of the parent repo.