# Some files in my git repo do not have history. What is wrong?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have git repo, I found that when using `git log myfile`, only files under the root (where the `.git` folder is) show logs. Doing the same to any file in a sub directory does not show anything. Why?

Similarly, when using *git extension*, right-clicking a file and clicking "file history", only files in root folder have history. All other files do not have history - it will say "git is not initialized"

Did I miss some settings?

Comment: have you added that files into index?

Comment: Yes, all files are in checked into the repo.

Comment: please provide the answer of `git show ignored_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One explanation would be a `.gitignore` which ignores sub-folders (`*/`)

That would explain that a `git add .` or a `git status` do nothing regarding said subfolders.
(Even though the OP thinks "all files have been added". If they actually are in the index, then the `.gitignore` rules don't apply, as [majioa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446267/majioa) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325429/some-files-in-my-git-repo-do-not-have-history-what-is-wrong#comment32151866_21326562))

Check also your environment variables (`GIT_DIR`, `GIT_WORK_TREE`) to see if they are set to anything that could confuse Git in your folder.

Do a `git ls-files --stage` in the root folder of your repo in order to check for [special entries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309) in [the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) which would explain why sub-folders content are of a different nature (a submodule being one).

Comment: `.gitignore` is affected only when a file in the igronred folder isn't added to index.

Comment: @majioa True. I have added that in the answer.

Comment: I notice that for the same repo, if I cloned it from remote site, then history is there, but if I copy the cloned repo to a new place, the history is not available anymore. What I can do to get the history information back?

Comment: @user386436 It depends on how you copy it to a new place (with or without its `.git`? with a `git clone`?)

Comment: with the .git folder, I can still use the repo for commit, push.