# Results of Merging a Branch Tracking a Remote with a Branch Containing a Submodule?

Tags: git-merge, git-submodules, git-remote

What happens when a branch containing a submodule and a branch tracking a remote are merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special: a submodule is just an [entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309), a [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309).

As long as that entry (like a folder name) doesn't conflict with the same name from the other branch, the merge will proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by 'As long as that entry…doesn't conflict with the same name from the other branch?'  Do you mean that such a merge will fail if there's a different file or folder with the same name in both branches?  For example, say that I have two branches, one in which I have a folder and another in which there is a folder with the same name which is actually a sub-module.  What would happen in this case?

Comment: A submodule is an folder entry. If you have the same folder name in the other branch (but not as a submodule), there will be a conflict (gitlink vs. plain folder): the merge will not proceed.

Comment: So I'd have to decouple the sub-module first.  That stinks; I was hoping that there might be a way for the sub-module to be recognized as an exact duplicate of a specific point in the other branch's history and, as a result, get merged successfully.

Comment: @RandomDSdevel I confirm: a submodule is like a nested git repo: its content won't be inspected/compared with a similar content of the parent repo.

Comment: So I'd have to do something along the lines of the procedure outlined [here](http://x3ro.de/2013/09/01/Integrating-a-submodule-into-the-parent-repository.html) first before I merged the two branches.

Comment: @RandomDSdevel yes, if you want to include the history of the submodule in your parent repo.