# Git command to force a particular commit in a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there a Git command to force a specific submodule/main module relationship or do I have to manually edit a file in the .git directory?

For example, my main program uses a library common to many projects, but I need to have a particular commit in the library tied to my main program.

I.e., I have been using submodules naively and the relationships are messed up, and I want to fix them.

Comment: You can check out a specific commit in a submodule. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a submodule is a way to record a specific SHA1 as a **[gitlink entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** in the [index of the parent repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309).

If somehow the submodule doesn't reflect the right SHA1, all you have to do is checkout the appropriate SHA1, go back to the parent repo, add and commit: that will record the new desired state of the submodule.