# Git Submodule in branch not master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-submodules

**EDIT:** According to @VonC in the comments I have a nested repo, not a submodule. However my problem remains the same below:

I created a branch off of my local repo to work on a new feature. The new feature required me to install the Azure PHP SDK via composer. Turns out that the Azure SDK has created a git repo of it's own within the `/vendor` folder. So I now have a Submodule in this new branch.

I have committed everything within this branch, and when I do `git status` I receive

```
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Now when I switch back to my master branch to merge this new feature branch and do a `git status` I see:

```
Untracked files : vendor/
```

I have googled and seen that if I `add` and `commit` this `vendor/` directory to the master branch, I will not be able to merge the new feature branch because of some sort of conflict. I think it will also mess up the submodule on the feature branch?!? I haven't tried to merge the new feature branch leaving the `vendor/` untracked because I am not sure it will work, and I am not sure what it might screw up.

How should I proceed? I am sitting on the master branch, with the new feature branch sitting there with a submodule in `vendor/`. And on the master branch the `vendor/` folder is in untracked files.

What do I do to merge the feature branch successfully in to master?

Comment: It is only a submodule if you have in your main repo a .gitmodules file, and if vendor is declared as a gitlink entry (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) in the index (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309). In your case, is vendor *really* a submodule? Or simply a nested git repo? (in which case, you could convert it to a submodule: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27561728/6309)

Comment: I don't appear to have a .gitmodules file. However I have pushed my feature branch to bitbucket and it says the Azure SDK folder in `vendor/` is a submodule... I am concerned as when in the feature branch my working directory is clean, but when I move back to the master branch it produces the error `warning: unable to rmdir irn/vendor/microsoft/windowsazure: Directory not empty` and then there is suddenly `vendor/` in untracked files...

Comment: In your `feature` branch, do you see a `.git/` *folder*, or a `.git` *file* in your `azure sdk` directory within the `vendor/` directory?

Comment: There is a `.git` **folder**. For completeness the folder structure is `vendor/microsoft/windowsazure/.git`

Comment: So it is a nested repo indeed, not a submodule. Not sure why bitbucket even see that folder.

Comment: Ah OK. Does that make things easier for me :-)

Comment: @VonC Now I know it is a nested repo, I still don't know how to merge the feature branch in to master. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to track the `"vendor"` directory in your git repo.

So I would just remove it (untrack it), commit the corresponding changes, and add the vendor directory into the project's `.gitignore` directory so that it remains untracked in the future.

The steps for this would be simply:

```
git checkout feature_branch
git rm -r --cached vendor
echo "vendor" >> .gitignore && git add .gitignore
git commit -m "untrack vendor directory"
```

The `--cached` flag above will keep the files locally even after the `git rm` in an untracked state.

FWIW, the contents of the vendor directory are dependencies that `Composer` installs, and they can be generated on the fly. As such, it should be part of your deployment script, so that you can setup your environment using composer and therefore should not be checked into your repo.

(Note: You might want to explore maintaining a shared soft links for common `vendor` in your deployment to avoid fresh download time during each build)

Quoting the [composer docs for `Should I commit the dependencies in my vendor directory?`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md)

> The general recommendation is no. The vendor directory (or wherever your dependencies are installed) should be added to `.gitignore`/`svn:ignore`/etc.
>
> The best practice is to then have all the developers use `Composer` to install the dependencies. Similarly, the build server, CI, deployment tools etc should be adapted to run Composer as part of their project bootstrapping.