# How to add git repo to other repo under subfolder

Tags: git, git-branch

I have git repo in folder `final_app` and I have to add new folder `app_part` which is already git project. When I copied and try `git add .` or `git add --all` but it doesn't want to add `app_part`. How to add files from `app_part` folder to `git repo final_app` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to not copy it and add that git repo as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):

```
cd final_app
git submodule add /url/of/repo/app_part/
git add .
git commit -m "Add app_part as submodule"
```

If you copy it directly, it is just a nested repo which will be ignored by the parent repo.

Adding it as a submodule means adding a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in your `final_app` index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309), referencing a SHA1 of the `app_part` repo.