# Why does git commit my file using references?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repository on bitbucket. The repository has two directories with files in it. After committing these directories git is showing me some kind of hash code for those files.

[image]

I expect that the directory names should be hyperlinks and I should be able to browse them on bitbucket.

On cloning the repository to my local system it is giving me empty directories.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize and update those **[git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**:

```
git submodule update --init
```

(See [`git submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) man page)

Those SHA1 are **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entries in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309).