# Privately manage public project - GIT

Tags: git, version-control

I am "following" a public project (e.g., [opencv](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv)): that is I `clone`ed it locally to my environment, and I am using it as a component of a larger project I am privately researching.

I would like to have my private version control (git) monitoring both my private code as well as changes I make to the public project (opencv).
Additionally, I would like to be able to keep the public project up-to-date according to its public version.

That is, I have a local project that has two gits controlling it: both the public git (from which I still want to be able to get occasional updates) and my local git (to which I commit all my changes, that I won't be committing to the public git).

How can I achieve this "dual git" repository?

Comment: I hope I made my question clear, I would be happy to clarify if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using it as a component of a larger project I am privately researching

If your larger project is itself a git repo (with a *private* upstream repo), you can add [`Itseez/opencv`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv) as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.
Or rather, you would add a **[fork of that repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)** as a submodule.

That way, you can keep your private repo private, while keeping a link to your fork in that same repo, and recording possible `opencv` modifications (or [updating `opencv` with new commits from the original repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)).

The parent private repo records a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309), which represents the state of the `opencv` submodule at a given time: if you do any new commit in the opencv submodule, you need to push them but *also* to add and commit the new SHA1 of that repo in your parent repo.

Comment: wow! I'm fairly inexperienced in git, it will take me a while to process this answer. Thank you very much!