# New Branch from Repo but Change the Submodules

Tags: git-submodules

I have a git repo that contains 2 submodules.  I want to create a new branch of the main app and have the submodules to point to a different "branch." I quote branch for I understand that submodules don't point to branches, but rather commit.  I don't want the branch option for I don't always want the latest commit from the subs. I can't find in documentation.  All three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply create a new branch in your main parent repo and then:

- go in each submodules
- checkout for each the right branch you want
- go back in the parent repo and add and commit: that will record the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309)) of the two submodules new SHA1.

Since you have not configured [the submodules to follow a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309), they will stay at the SHA1 you checked out for each of them.