# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'craft/config'

Tags: git

I've changed some database settings in a project and can't commit the DB file. It doesn't even show up as modified. This codebase is copied from another Craft site I built, which a new repository was created for. It is running Craft CMS 2.6.2903.

```
$ git add craft/config/db.php
fatal: Pathspec 'craft/config/db.php' is in submodule 'craft/config'

fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'craft/config'
```

There's no .gitmodules file in the repo (or in any of my other Craft sites) and it doesn't make sense for the DB file or the other config files to be in a submodule.

I'm really confused now as I can't even find a relevant reference to that submodule in the .git folder.

```
grep -ro "craft/config" .
Binary file ./index matches
```

Given I can't find it I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Hi James... Despite the fact that you're using Craft, this is very much a **git** question. Craft itself doesn't contain anything git related by default. For that reason, we'll migrate this to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi Lindsey. Quite right. Thanks for that.

Comment: Is there a `.git` file in `craft/config/`?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that craft/config folder is actually a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309) recording a SHA1 for a submodule)

Check the output of `git ls-tree HEAD craft/config` (no trailing `/`)

The fix is simple `git rm --cached craft/config` (again: no trailing `/`)

Then you can add again `craft/config`.