# Working in a git branch with submodules and commiting directly from that branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am working in my branch and I needed an external submodule, so from the root of my project I did.

```
git submodule add https://github.com/blah/blah ./location/submodue
Cloning into ...
...
git commit -am "Added submodule"
```

This seems to have worked and I was able to carry on working on the main branch, while working I noticed a bug in the submodule, so I made the change directly in it.

But when I did a `git add .` no changes were found, the code changes I made were not found. There was nothing to commit but git did report `git +0 ~1 -0!`, but I was not able to add/commit that one change.

So I made the changes to the 'main' project, then I pulled the changes and everything was fine again.

So how can I make changes to the submodule and commit those changes from the 'main' branch that uses that submodule

(Let me know if you want the links/paths to the actual github projects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I make changes to the submodule and commit those changes from the 'main' branch that uses that submodule

You need to:

- make sure your submodule has checked out a branch: by default, a submodule is always in a **[detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)**, checking out a SHA1, not a branch.

You can make each submodule follow a branch.
See "[How to make an existing submodule track a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)".

```
cd /path/to/your/parent/repo/Foo
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.bar1.branch branch1
```

- make a new commit (fix) in that branch, and push to the remote repo of that submodule (or a fork)
- go back to the parent repo, add, commit and push in order to record the new SHA1 of that submodule. (that is: the [**gilink**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309), a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309))